# In C#, what is analogous to the CHAR_BIT from C++? Fast Abs

Tags: c#, c++

Does C# have something analogous to C++'s [CHAR_BIT](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/limits.html#CHAR_BIT)?

**Update:**
Basically, I'm trying to compute abs without branching, here is the C++ version:

```
// Compute the integer absolute value (abs) without branching

int v;           // we want to find the absolute value of v
unsigned int r;  // the result goes here 
int const mask = v >> sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1;

r = (v ^ mask) - mask;
```

Here is my C# version:

```
private int Abs(int value)
{
    int mask = value >> sizeof(int) * 8 - 1;
    return ((value ^ mask) - mask);
}
```

Strangely, this also works:

```
private int Abs(int value)
{
    int mask = value >> sizeof(int) * sizeof(byte) - 1;
    return ((value ^ mask) - mask);
}
```

Comment: I doubt it.  `char` is understood to represent a unicode character.  All other builtin types are understood to use a set number of bits.  It will not vary and thus have no need to store this information anywhere else.

Comment: @JeffM: A char can't (usually) represent a unicode character in either C++ or C#. In C# it can only hold a sinlge UTF-16 _code unit_ which may map on to one or fewer unicode characters. In C++ a `char` is usually only 8-bits, unless it's at least 21-bits it can't hold a unicode character.

Comment: @Charles: I'm fully aware of that.  The point I was trying to make was that C++ type sizes may vary between implementations/architectures/whatever.  In C#, everything is fixed in the language specification and keeping track of the bits used is unnecessary.  Answering his question on the existence of a C# equivalent of the `CHAR_BIT` macro, "I doubt it."  It's enough to find out how many bytes a type occupies using the `sizeof` operator then determine the number of bits from that.  p.s., unicode character, probably the wrong term for this but the idea is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you consider `byte` in C# to be the equivalent of C++'s `char` then the closest equivalent of `CHAR_BIT` is `8`. In C# a `byte` is guaranteed to be exactly 8 bits.

Comment: `sizeof` is a size in bytes in both C# and C++ so it's completely different from `CHAR_BIT`. What exactly are you using `CHAR_BIT` for?

Comment: @Charles, scratch the last comment... I was looking at [sizeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) different things in C# and for some reason I thought I saw sizeof(byte) is 8, but it's 1. In any case, I'm writing a c++ style [fast abs](http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs) and this seems to work regardless that I'm not using 8 instead of CHAR_BIT: `public int Abs(int value)
        {
            int mask = value >> sizeof(int) * sizeof(byte) - 1;
            return ((value ^ mask) - mask);
        }`

Comment: @Link: Really? You think that'll be faster than `Math.Abs()`? You think Microsoft has COBOL coders writing their math routines? Why do you believe yours will be faster than something that's probably heavily optimised assembly code?

Comment: @paxdiablo Ok... when you put it that way... but I can test mine and theirs to see which one is faster.

Comment: @Link, that's a good idea. I have my suspicions which way the scales will fall but it's still worth testing, just in case.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I'm with you on that one, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent is the literal `8` because a [`byte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is always 8-bit long.

Comment: And PI saved in a single precission floating point may always be 3.1415927410125732421875. No reason for me to remember that number and type it: we use variables not only because of their value, but also because of their name.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need it, because size of primitive C# types is fixed. It's guaranteed that int is a 32-bit integer, long is 64-bit integer and so on.